# Importing a feature of phpFox to SocialEngine

Tags: javascript, variables, socialengine, phpfox

phpFox has released a theme named "Nebula" with the version 3.5.0. On this theme, there is button on the Header and the menu slides down when the user clicks the button. (Actually not a button, but a div)

I want to add this feature to SocialEngine. But JavaScript Code contains a phpFox variable and I don't know what it refers to. I am not so good at JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div id="nb_features">
  <a href="#" id="nb_features_link">Features</a>
  <div id="nb_features_holder">
    Menu widget code will be added here...
  </div>                                
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$Behavior.customNebula = function(){

    $('#nb_features_link').click(function(){

        if ($(this).hasClass('nb_is_clicked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('nb_is_clicked');
            $('#nb_features_holder').slideUp('fast');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('nb_is_clicked');
            $('#nb_features_holder').slideDown('fast');
        }

        return false;
    });
};
```

CSS:

```
#nb_features {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#nb_features_link,
#nb_features_link:hover {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;   
    text-indent:-1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(~/application/modules/Wonder/externals/images/nb_features_link.png') no-repeat;
    margin-top:-7px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#nb_features_link:hover {
    background:#334d83 url(~/application/modules/Wonder/externals/images/nb_features_link.png') no-repeat;
}

#nb_features a.nb_is_clicked,
#nb_features a.nb_is_clicked:hover {
    background:#334d83 url(~/application/modules/Wonder/externals/images/nb_features_link.png') no-repeat;
}

#nb_features_holder {
    position:absolute;
    background:#4f4f4f;
    right:0px;
    width:980px;    
    border:1px #304779 solid;
    border-top:0px;
    display:none;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#nb_features_holder ul li a,
#nb_features_holder ul li a:hover {
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nb_features_holder ul li a.menu_is_selected,
#nb_features_holder ul li a.menu_is_selected:hover {
    background:#009AEF;
    color:#fff;
}

#nb_features_holder ul li a:hover {
    background:#2F2F2F;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease;      
}
```

What should I do to make this code work with SocialEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the $Behavior namespace is a wrapper for the onLoad event, is this the js variable you were talking about? If it is you can replace it for the more conventional jquery/mootools/etc way and it would probably work although you would have to match the selectors properly, dont know if the code you posted is everything you need

Comment: This is the code that works on phpFox. I just need to know what changes should be done to make this code work on SocialEngine. When I apply this as a widget, I get this error on Chrome Debug: Uncaught ReferenceError: $Behavior is not defined

Comment: Yes, that is what I was talking about, try replacing $Behavior with the normal document.ready handler, I dont know if Social Engine uses JQuery but if it does this should help http://api.jquery.com/ready/